# Problem in 'make' for installing CP210x driver to my Raspberry Pi

Tags: driver

My kernal version is 3.18.11-v7+. Since the kernels from the Raspberry Pi Foundation kernels don't ship with a build directory, I installed the Debian-style package, which should include the build directory using

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-image-rpi-rpfv linux-headers-rpi-rpfv
```

Then I appended this at end of /boot/config.txt

```
  # Parameters to boot on raspbian kernel (linux-image-rpi-rpfv package)
    kernel=vmlinuz-3.18.11-v7+
   initramfs initrd.img-3.18.11-v7+ followkernel
```

After I reboot,the screen goes blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that kernel requires an `initramfs`?  I have not seen any that do on the pi, since it is a very specific hardware platform and the kernels are built exclusively for it.  The purpose of an initramfs on normal PC distros is to facilitate the use of a wide range of hardware (based on information from the BIOS or other scanning, the kernel can pick which of a number of mutually exclusive drivers to load from inside the initramfs so that can mount the root filesystem).  So I would ditch that line.

I can't find those packages in [the Raspbian repos](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/linux-3.18/), but note that a "kernel headers" package does *not* include the source, which is what you need.

If cross compiling is an option, I'd recommend you get [the 3.18 rpi kernel source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.18.y) directly.  Since this is for the ARMv7 pi 2, pre-built cross-compilers are available on all mainstream linux distros, which saves you a major hassle.  To create the default configuration, just use `make bcmrpi_defconfig` (that's what's used with the Raspbian kernels).  You can also compile on the pi, but it will take a long time, as in hours.

---

If you do build against that source, the module created may or may not work with your current kernel; it likely may not.  This will be clear one way or the other when you go to load it, because it will say something about "mismatched" symbols.

If so, you need to use a kernel built from the source you used to build the module (the issue is versioning; you can't use a module built against 3.17.1 with 3.17.2, and sometimes this gets even more finicky).  In this case, possibly the kernel was already built when making the module -- the unfortunate part will be that it was not configured properly if you did not run `make bcmrpi_config` earlier.  Check for a `.config` file in the top of the source tree, and if it is there:

```
mv .config .config-tmp
make bcmrpi_defconfig
diff .config .config-tmp
```

If `.config` didn't exist, or these are substantially different, you need to build the kernel (again).  Run `make bcmrpi_defconfig` if you have not yet, then:

```
make -j4
make -j4 modules_install
```

These first two will take a long time on the pi.  Then:

```
make install
```

There should be a new kernel in `boot` probably called `vmlinuz` although it may have a more elaborate name (`make install` will say what it is).  You want to use that in `/boot/config.txt` as your `kernel=`.

Comment: I installed the rpi source and then called make in the cp210x driver as per the build instructions. It is now two hours since I did it. But the compiling is taking too long.. It is running many commands like CC [M]  drivers/net/wireless/b43/pio.o
  CC [M]  drivers/net/wireless/b43/rfkill.o
  CC [M]  drivers/net/wireless/b43/ppr.o
  CC [M]  drivers/net/wireless/b43/leds.o
  LD [M]  drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.o
  CC [M]  drivers/net/wireless/b43legacy/main.o
  
I dont know if I did something wrong

Comment: No, it will take a long time if it needs to build a lot (or the whole) of the kernel, which it might.  Builds produce a lot of output that may even include various `warning: `s, but anything that's a real error will be clearly indicated and cause the build to fail immediately.  Not failing a build doesn't prove the software it produced works, though.   I've added a few last paragraphs above that contains a further caveat.  Note that on the pi 2 you can save much time compiling by using that `-j4` switch to make, which will parallelize the build.